AT25SF081 SPI Flash Waveform relative to FPGA testbench
I am now looking to understand more on the IO waveforms on the AT25SF081 Flash memory documentation in relation to the controlling device.
Are the waveforms in the document from the 'point of view' of the Flash component, or the FPGA device controlling it?

The "AC Waveforms" (figures 13-1 to 13-5) relate to both the Flash component and to the device that you use to control it.  These waveform diagrams are to be used in conjunction with the "AC Characteristics" (tables 12.4, etc.).
For example, Figure 13-1 shows the waveforms for a serial data input operation.  Three signals are inputs to the Flash component: CS, SCK and SI.  You must connect your device (an FPGA, for example) to those pins and drive the pins according to the timing requirements in the figure and tables.
You must provide the clock signal (SCK), and its minimum clock period must be 10ns.  It is fine to provide a 20ns period, but a period of 8ns is not guaranteed to work.  An 8ns period does not satisfy the timing requirement of the Flash datasheet.

Ah ok thanks - so the waveforms that the testbench produce should be exactly matching the ones in docs linked in the post in order to observe the desired behaviour?

@K_T: Yes, the waveforms need to match in the sense that they need to satisfy the timing requirements as set by the datasheet.

The waveforms are from the actual waveforms point of view of as seen on the bus. Not from point of view of the flash chip or any specific device driving the bus.
